# Python date time comparison with None value (Landscape API)

Tags: python, api

I am cutting some data from web service one of parameters is last_ping_time witch can be at some point None value. I am comparing current date with last_ping_time to check communication with machine.
So I get

*ValueError: time data 'None' does not match format '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ'*

I tried to set dummy value if I get None

```
   if ping=="None":

   ping="2013-01-01T00:00:00
```

Tried also break or continue nut they don't seem to work this error persists. I need loop continue to next value if null or put some dummy value and also continue.
I am out of ideas, please help.

```
with open(filename, 'wb') as csvfile:   #Creating report file
    spamwriter = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter='    ')
    for computer in computers:

        ping=computer["last_ping_time"]
        ping=str(ping)
        ping.split('T')
        if ping=="None":
        #break
        ping="2013-01-01T00:00:00"  
        else

                ping=datetime.datetime.strptime(ping, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ') # Convert string to data

                if ping<Current_Date: 
                        #toremove=count+1
                        os.system('zenity --info --text="Computers not contacting more than 30 days:%s "' % (computer["hostname"]))
                        #print "Needs to be deleted" #Control Variable

                        spamwriter.writerow((computer["id"], computer["hostname"], computer["title"], computer["last_ping_time"], "30 Days from last contact machine will be be removed"))
                else:
                        network=str(computer) #list to string
                        ip=network.split("u'ip_address': u'")[1] #1 shows what is after parameters
                        ip=ip.split("'")[0] #0 shows what is before parameters
                        mac=network.split("u'mac_address': u'")[1]
                        mac=mac.split("'")[0] 
                        print mac
                        print ip
                        spamwriter.writerow((computer["id"], computer["hostname"], computer["title"], computer["last_ping_time"], mac, ip)) 
os.system('zenity --info --text="Report is created with name:%s "' % (filename))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove `ping = str(ping)` line and use:

```
if ping is None:
   # no last ping time
```